# Parse a XML from a string that contains other additional rubbish in php

Tags: php, xml, string, parsing

I'm making a connection to a payment gateway that is supposed to return a XML string that I should parse. However, the string that is returned by the WS includes a HTML header before the actual XML.

I already talked to the tech guys in there and they say that thats how their system works and I should manage my way with that.

So my questions is: is there a clean easy way of extracting only the XML from the string and ditch the rest?

Thanks!

### Thanks for all the responses! I added an example below.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 300
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 15:02:17 GMT

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?><Inicio><Nrocom>xxxxxx</Nrocom><Nroterm>xxxxxx</Nroterm><Moneda>858</Moneda><Importe>000</Importe><Plan>001</Plan><Tcompra>0</Tcompra><Info></Info><Rsp>2222</Rsp><Idtrn>000000</Idtrn></Inicio>Thread was being aborted.Thread was being aborted.
```

This whole block is a normal response from this gateway. Disregard the "Thread was being aborted.Thread was being aborted." message, they say they are working on that.

Comment: Really this should be their problem, but can you post an example of what the faulty XML looks like?

Comment: Show us an example of the response, I'd even dare say you can load the whole thing up with the simplexml class and export from the node you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very lean example of one possibility without the knowledge of the data you're working with.

```
$string = '
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <xmlroot>
      <item>hello</item>
      <item>world</item>
    </xmlroot>
  </body>
</html>
';

if($xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string) and $item = $xml->xpath('//xmlroot'))
{
  echo $item[0]->asXML();
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the 'and' keyword. This could be rewritten as:

`if(($xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string)) && ($item = $xml->xpath('//xmlroot')))`

Not as pretty perhaps, but a lot less likely to throw people off.

Answer (score 0):

So I just saw your edit, what you want to do is find `<?xml` and parse only this.

```
$beginTag = "<?xml";
$xmlDoc = substr($response, strpos($response, $beginTag));

echo $xmlDoc;
```

This code gives this output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?><Inicio><Nrocom>xxxxxx</Nrocom><Nroterm>xxxxxx</Nroterm><Moneda>858</Moneda><Importe>000</Importe><Plan>001</Plan><Tcompra>0</Tcompra><Info></Info><Rsp>2222</Rsp><Idtrn>000000</Idtrn></Inicio>Thread was being aborted.Thread was being aborted.
```

Obviously, the `XML` is not valid, but I guess when the `Thread was being aborted.` problem will be fixed you will receive valid XML!

Answer (score 0):

Well I sort of got it working somehow.

Don't take this as a perfect solutions. I am pretty sure there are many other better ways of doing this cause I kinda had to "learn" regular expressions to get it.

The idea is simple, use regex to get the `<?xml` tag and the ending tag of the XML. The function preg_match() then returns everything in between in the $matches array.

Hope it helps.

```
<?php
$exp = '/<\?xml.*<\/Inicio>/';
preg_match($exp, $string, $matches ,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
echo $matches[0][0];
?>
```